# Como verificar se todos os elementos de uma lista satisfazem a uma mesma condição utilizando uma expressão lambda?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma classe que representa um entidade no banco de dados. Essa classe roda uma *procedure* que retorna os dados dela. Criei uma lista do tipo e essa lista vem carregada. Vamos supor que essa seja a lista carregada: `vlstMinhaEntidade`. Como eu faço para percorrer essa lista com *lambda*?

Pessoal, `for` e `foreach`, isso eu sei. A questão seria com *lambda*. Desse jeito não funcionou. O objetivo disso é somente aprendizado.

```
var teste = l in vlstMinhaEntidade...
```

Da forma acima dá erro em tudo.

Assim está dando pau:

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.ForEach(
   l => l.IcObrigatorio == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento)
);
```

Comment: Não devo ter entendido a pergunta porque List implementa isso: `vlsMinhaEntidade.ForEach(item => qualquerAçao(item));`

Comment: Você quer percorrer e realizar que tipo de ação?

Comment: Eu vi você fazendo isto tantas vezes, achei que já soubesse. Não sei bem o que você que mas acho que seria algo assim: vlsMinhaEntidade.ForEach(l => /* faz algo aqui */);`

Comment: você poderia postar um exemplo completo utilizando for, apenas para que possamos entender o que você quer alcançar usando linq?

Comment: acho que o que você quer fazer é uma busca e não executar uma ação e para isso você precisa fazer um `Where`. O `ForEach` serve para executar ações para cada item iterado. Ou seja `vlstDados.Where(l => l.IcObrigatorio == 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento))`

Comment: @Ninita, assim não dá erro, mas tem como eu setar a minha variável booleana direto? Tipo(assim dá erro) mas a idéia seria essa: vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.Where(l => l.IcObrigatorio == 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento)); ou teria que pegar o resultado e num if setar

Comment: Para isso você pode usar o `Any` que verifica se existem itens que cumpram a condição: `vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.Any(l => l.IcObrigatorio == 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocumento));` e portanto o resultado é bool

Comment: @Ninita, valeu. Obrigado pela resposta. Vou trocar pelo Any, mas lembrando que o All não me deu erro, mas não sei se está funcionando, porque ainda não testei, fá-lo-ei agora.

Comment: @pnet só vi agora a sua resposta usando o `All`. Mas sim, o `All` também pode funcionar mas tudo depende do que você necessita. Se apenas quer verificar se existe algum item que cumpra a condição basta usar o `Any`, mas se quer verificar se todos os itens cumprem a condição então deve usar o `All`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz assim e resolveu com All:

```
vbolErroDocTorObrigatorio = vlstDados.All(l => l.IcObrigatorio == 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DsPathDocume
```

Peguei a resposta no SO em inglês.

Comment: O método All verifica uma mesma condição em todos os elementos da lista. Baseado na sua solução, sugiro que sua pergunta seja renomeada para "Como verificar se todos os elementos de uma lista satisfazem a uma mesma condição utilizando uma expressão lambda."